# superagent doesn't return response

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, superagent

I am trying to send request with query string this way but nothing is logged in the console. I want to do something with the returned result but **res** and **err** are both nothing.

```
superagent
        .get('http://localhost:4000/v1/process/web')
        .query({user: 'nux'})
        .then(res => console.log(res.body))
        .catch(e => console.error(e));
```

this how router looks like

```
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/web', async (req, res) => {
    res.send(req.query);
});
```

What is wrong with these codes?

Comment: You are sending requests to `/v1/process/web` your get route must be `/v1/process/web`

Comment: @matrixersp I use it  as ``app.use('/v1/process', webRouter);`` so the router is correct because It works on browser

Comment: @matrixersp the request is sent the only problem, nothing is returned

Comment: can you log thing in your express server

Comment: You're sending `req.query` from the server which is an empty object in your case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a minimal working example:

`app.js`:

```js
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const app = express();

router.get("/web", (req, res) => {
  res.send(req.query);
});

app.use("/v1/process", router);

module.exports = app;
```

`app.test.js`:

```js
const app = require("./app");
const superagent = require("superagent");
const { expect } = require("chai");

describe("57953567", () => {
  let server;
  const port = 4000;
  before((done) => {
    server = app.listen(port, () => {
      console.info(`HTTP server is listening on http://localhost:${server.address().port}`);
      done();
    });
  });
  after((done) => {
    server.close(done);
  });
  it("should pass", () => {
    return superagent
      .get("http://localhost:4000/v1/process/web")
      .query({ user: "nux" })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.body);
        expect(res.body).to.be.eql({ user: "nux" });
        expect(res.status).to.be.equal(200);
      });
  });
});
```

Integration test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
 57953567
HTTP server is listening on http://localhost:4000
{ user: 'nux' }
    ✓ should pass


  1 passing (39ms)

-------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File         |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
-------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files    |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 app.js      |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 app.test.js |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
-------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/mocha-chai-sinon-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/57953567